# Compile error on Serializable when compiling with OpenJdk11

Tags: java, serialization, java-11, openjdk-11, adoptopenjdk

I am getting compilation error when compiling a Jdk8 codebase with OpenJdk11 on Serializable class with error : The type java.io.Serializable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4:compile (default) on project test-proj: Compiler errors:
[ERROR] error at public abstract class HiberTypeMapper implements UserType, Serializable {
[ERROR]                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] /dev_loc/test-proj/src/main/java/com/hiber/HiberTypeMapper.java:13:0::0 The type java.io.Serializable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4:compile (default) on project il-commons: Compiler errors:
error at public abstract class HiberTypeMapper implements UserType, Serializable {
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
/dev_loc/test-proj/src/main/java/com/hiber/HiberTypeMapper.java:13:0::0 The type java.io.Serializable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
```

The class which it is complaining on

```
package com.hiber;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;


public abstract class HiberTypeMapper implements UserType, Serializable {
...
}
```

My versions are :

```
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T15:39:06-04:00)
Maven home: /Users/jogi/Apps/apache-maven-3.5.0
Java version: 11.0.7, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Please suggest the solution, Serializable interface is part of java.base module, so why the compiler is giving error.

Comment: Can we see your `pom.xml`?

Comment: @JacobG - The pom.xml is pretty much what I was using with Jdk8. But I have updated few things, like maven-compiler-plugin version to 3.8.0. from 3.0. And aspect-maven-plugin to version 1.11 from 1.4.  The pom.xml is pretty big and it has reference of all our internal libraries and third party libraries. Is it possible, if I can send a certain section of it?

Comment: "And aspect-maven-plugin to version 1.11 from 1.4" - It shows `1.4` in the compiler error that you posted.

Comment: @JacobG Thats a good point. Since the aspectj-maven-plugin version was defined in dependency-management, so it had to be refreshed. The error which I raised on Serializable, is no longer happening. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Jacob G. helped resolving it that it could be due to aspectj-maven-plugin version. For OpenJdk11, version 1.4 will not work. After upgrading it to 1.11, this error is no longer occurring.